# How to implement ObversableCollectionChanged in nested ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xaml

I want to subscribe to an ObservableCollectionChanged event but I am not really sure at which location to implement it correctly.

I have a ViewModel that contains a ObservableCollection, that contains a ObservableCollection.

```
ViewModel
    (has property) ObservableCollection<Member> 
        (has property) ObservableCollection<Promotion>
        Subscribe to this CollectionChanged
```

My first intention was to subscribe to the Event in the MainWindow.xaml.cs Code but I think the correct way should be in the "Promotion" Class that is instantiated as ObservableCollection property in the Member Class?

What I want to achieve:
Update Database with new Items if they are added to the Collection

EDIT:

Example code

```
private class ViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Member> Members;
}

private class Member : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Promotion> Promotions;
}
```

How can I subscribe to the ObservableCollection< Promotion> CollectionChanged Event from within the ViewModel Class?

Comment: You need to add some code around your question and mention / tag the framework you're using (.xaml?)

Comment: what does _"Subscribe to this CollectionChanged"_ mean? Why should you subscribe to any `CollectionChanged` event? If you should subscribe to any, why wouldn't you subscribe to the one corresponding to the collection you care about? If you care about when new items are added to `ObservableCollection<Member>` then subscribe to that. If you care about when new items are added to `ObservableCollection<Promotion>`, then subscribe to that. Please improve the question, so it's clear what you are actually asking.